# findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock Parse not working

Tags: ios, parse-platform, pfquery

We are using "findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock" method of PFQuery to query some table of our Parse database. The Table contains 23.3k rows. We are querying for a particular "EmailId" in the table. This find method is working randomly. It sometimes does not returns me the object whereas the email id exists in the table.
Is there any limit restrictions.

My code snippet is :

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:Login_Table];

[query whereKey:Login_Email equalTo:[user.userEmail lowercaseString]];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error) {
         // The find succeeded.
         NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %lu scores.", (unsigned long)objects.count);

         if ([objects count] > 0)
         {
             loginResult(YES,objects);
         }
         else
         {
             loginResult(NO,objects);
         }
     }
     else {
         // Log details of the failure

         loginResult(NO,objects);
         NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     }
 }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple query with no constraints to obtain up to **100** objects,  but anything from **1** to **1000** is a valid limit.

You need to query again for the next objects by setting **limit** and **skip** properties of PFQuery. Similarly you need to query again and again until you reach your total count.

Follow the guide : https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide

Comment: The default limit of Parse is not 100. It is 1000.

Comment: @kingspeech By default, results are limited to 100, but anything from 1 to 1000 is a valid limit (From Parse Docs). Check my updated answer.